# How to convert String to array, and remove quotation marks in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, meteor, google-visualization

I want to convert the following String to an array:

```
str = " ['GHR',  15, 14    ], ['GHR',  12, 20  ] ";
array = new Array (str);
```

when I do : 
    console.log(array );

it gives me:
   ["   ['GHR',  15, 14    ], ['GHR',  12, 20  ]  "] ,

but I want the result without quotation marks like:

[['GHR',  15, 14    ], ['GHR',  12, 20  ]]

Kindly, how to remove only the first and last quotation marks from the beginning and the end of the array?
I'm using this method to get data from mongodatabse then convert the results to rows that google charts can read them, in Metero platform

Comment: if you **really really really** trust the string - try using `eval`

Comment: One possible approach: `arr = JSON.parse('[' + str.replace(/'/g, '"') + ']');`

Comment: Can you not get this array in a more sensible format to begin with? Like valid JSON?

Comment: eval give me only ['GHR', 12, 20 ].. I don't know why.. I tried Json before with no luck, but I'll test  raina77ow's approach is working.. thank you all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use JSON.parse which will require you to swap out the single quotes

```
var str = " ['GHR',  15, 14    ], ['GHR',  12, 20  ] ";
var arr = JSON.parse("[" + str.replace(/'/g,'"') + "]");
```

or you can use new Function

```
var str = " ['GHR',  15, 14    ], ['GHR',  12, 20  ] ";
var arr = (new Function( "return [" + str + "]")());
```

Or get whatever is outputting it to make an array to start with or make it valid JSON so it can be parsed correctly.

Comment: Using the Function constructor is just a long winded way of calling *eval*, isn't it?

Comment: eval cut the first part of the array... but The function is working for me.. Thank you..epascarello.. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

Try below

```js
var str = " ['GHR',  15, 14    ], ['GHR',  12, 20  ] ";
str = str.replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
var arr = str.split('],').join(']|').split('|');
console.log(arr);
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zo3yvqbL/1/

Comment: The output is an array with two strings, not an array with two arrays. `[" ['GHR', 15, 14 ]", " ['GHR', 12, 20 ] "]`

Comment: that's true, the output is an array with two strings.. not what I need., thank you Anand G